# Исключения при подключении к базе данных JAVA

Tags: java, android, postgresql

Сделал подключение к локальной базе данных, все работает, но когда интернет на телефоне отсутствует, либо подключен мобильный интернет, то приложение просто вылетает. Делал исключения на ошибку подключения к БД, но не помогло.

```
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
    retMsg = "false";
    conmsg = null;
    return null;
}

if (connection != null) {
    System.out.println("You successfully connected to database now");
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed to make connection to database");
    retMsg = "false";
    conmsg = null;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @AlexKrass не помогло

Comment: try {
                connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                System.out.println("gshtss");

            } catch (SQLTimeoutException e){
                System.out.println("check point");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
                retMsg = "false";
                conmsg = null;
                return null;
            }

Comment: Да, разработчик драйвера может переписать этот метод и выдать еще другой вид Exception, надо тогда смотреть в документацию драйвера. К примеру, мой Postgresql выдает на отсутствие соединение PSQLException. Проще всего будет в конце сделать перехват общего исключения Exception без типизации: `catch (Exception e) { ... }`.

Comment: @AlexKrass ну это первое, что сделал, но тоже не помогло, может это все из-за того, что я это в AsyncTask делаю и там свой TimeOutException есть

Comment: И с какой ошибкой приложение вылетает?

Comment: @Maxim ну вот что в Run показывает I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29940 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Comment: Ну если на этом участке кода общий Exception не отловился, значит проблема скорее всего в другом месте. А может в нескольких сразу т.к. неустановленное соединение может тянуть за собой сбои в других местах приложения: к примеру может вы пытаетесь использовать соединение, которое не открылось. Можно делать дебаг проще: закоментировать этот участок кода оставив только `return null;` и если ошибка сохранится, это 100% не этот участок и идти выше/ниже по коду)) А так без самодостаточного примера больше сказать ничего не могу.

Comment: @AlexKrass сделал как вы сказали, ошибок не выскочило, значит проблема все-таки в этом месте

Comment: Предполагаю следующее: `if (connection != null)` не является гарантом того, что соединение на самом деле установилось. И при попытке использовать этот объект Connection, дальше по коду вылетает ошибка. Можно попробовать считать соединение установленным при успешном выполнении запроса к БД, какой-нибудь ненапряжный 'select 1' и более тщательно обрабатывать другие запросы.

Comment: Конечно, есть еще подозрение на переменные retMsg и conmsg, которые выдают повторное исключение при их неправильным использовании. В любом случае самодостаточный пример был бы лучше, чем так гадать, поскольку этот участок кода выглядит вполне работоспособным.

Comment: @AlexKrass ну я эту часть кода оставлял, где if (connection != null) и ошибок не выдавало, когда закоментировал try-catch. Вся проблема в том, что выполнение кота стопориться на .getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); и дальше не идет, после него println добавил и его не отображало

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо большое за ответы, оказалось все очень просто, поменял драйвер Gradle с org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4.jre7 на org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4.jre6 и все заработало

Answer (score 1):

Решилось все заменой драйвера с org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4.jre7 на org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4.jre6. Всем спасибо!